# Qt on Mac and QWidget's closeEvent

Tags: qt

Silly question, but can I know at the time of the window's "CloseEvent" event if the window is being closed because it received a cmd-q keystroke, or a cmd-w keystroke?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to understand how an user has closed your application you can install filter on `QApplication` and check every keystrokes here. If you encounter one of those you can do something: log it, send signal, set global flag etc. With global flag you can know for sure in close event if some keystroke has been used.